# UICollectionView cells doesn't appear

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I don't understand what's happening with my UICollectionView.
I'm apologise in advance because I think the answer is very simple

I just wan't to create a UICollectionView programmatically with 4 cells but 2 of them does not appear I don't know why

Here my code:

```
class NewsListViewController: UIViewController {

   public var newsImagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
       if self.newsImagesCollectionView == nil {
           self.createNewsImagesCollectionView()
       }
   }

   fileprivate func createNewsImagesCollectionView() {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    self.newsImagesCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    self.newsImagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.newsImagesCollectionView.delegate = self

    self.newsImagesCollectionView.register(NewsImagesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NewsImagesCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

       self.newsImagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow

       self.newsImagesCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.view.addSubview(self.newsImagesCollectionView)

       self.newsImagesCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       self.newsImagesCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
       self.newsImagesCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
       self.newsImagesCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
   }
}

extension NewsListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 4
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NewsImagesCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NewsImagesCollectionViewCell

       switch indexPath.row {
       case 0:
           cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .purple
       case 1:
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .green
       case 2:
           cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .orange
       case 3:
           cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .red
       default:
           cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
       }
       cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       cell.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "euro")
       return cell
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       print(self.view.frame.width)
       return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 4, height: self.view.frame.height)
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
       return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
   }
}
```

And I get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEHhC.png)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Does your collection view has the same size than your main view? because you calculating the size with the main view, is better if you use the collection view size.

return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 4, height: collectionView frame.height)